# How to determine location from which Windows 10 UWP app was installed with App Installer

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, appx, appinstaller

We have an app installed via the Windows 10 [App Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-file-overview). We have multiple environments, so the installer could point to different servers to get download updates. How can we determine in Windows what server our app is looking to for updates?

We would like to be able to do this in Windows via PowerShell or something similar. We are aware that the app itself can use the PackageManager and Package classes to determine this at runtime, but we do not want to change our app's code.

**Edit:** To clarify, we have automatic updates working. But we need a way to determine whether an installed app is pointing to Server1 vs Server2 for its updates.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/

Comment: @magicandre1981, I cannot find anything in this article which addresses my need to determine where an installed app is pointed to for updates.

Comment: you have XY problem, ask a different question about your real issue. follow the steps to get your apps updated

Comment: @magicandre1981 could you help me understand what is not clear in my original question? I feel that it fairly clearly says that I'm looking for a way to know where an app is pointed for updates. I'm not asking about how to *configure* updates. We already have that working.

Comment: If the automatic updates works, You could update one of services and then check which app get the update then determine the service.

Comment: In the app you can find the install Uri using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.getappinstallerinfo?view=winrt-19041, I do not think the URL is accessible in Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this didn't exist years ago, when this question was asked, but now the answer is as simple as:

```powershell
Get-AppxPackageAutoUpdateSettings -PackageFamilyName xyz
```

The output contains the row: `AppInstallerUri: https://example.com[...]`

I guess you could isolate that by running:

```powershell
(Get-AppxPackageAutoUpdateSettings -PackageFamilyName xyz).AppInstallerUri
```